# How do I get my website to display correctly?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm just learning to build a website.  It's a school project and after I upload through FileZilla, it became like this.

my website is:`www.sevenwonders.mezoka.com`

Here is the picture:
    http://i396.photobucket.com/albums/pp44/yoyoyaya_2008/Capture-13.jpg

I have no idea how to put the URL then display the webpage right away. Why does it display like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, because your website seems to be no longer available ...

Since URLs are case sensitive and your website has a file `Index.html` it will probably not work, it should be `index.html` (lower case `i`) instead.

It's generally a good idea to use lowercase filenames, so you don't have to constantly check the correct case, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: Oh just that? silly me! awesome, it works now. thanks so much!